# composer requireコマンドでlaravel breeze導入時に「Operation not permitted」という警告が出てパッケージが導入できない

Tags: php, docker, laravel, composer

laravel breezeを導入する際 `composer require laravel/breeze --dev` コマンドでパッケージインストールを試みるが、rootユーザーなのに

```
Failed to extract laravel/breeze: (1) '/usr/bin/unzip' -qq '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/tmp-978aba6437332f1f74f5fb0d8744aa25.zip' -d '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/acc1afe2'

chmod (directory attributes) error: Operation not permitted
fchmod (file attributes) error: Operation not permitted
```

以下同様のwarningが出力されインストール出来ません。
解決方法をご教授頂けると幸いです。

追記：
ホストOSはWindows、WSLでLinux環境を構築してDockerを導入し、Ubuntuのターミナルから `root@コンピュータ名:/mnt/c/users/ユーザー名/laravel_project/プロジェクト名/vendor/bin/sail composer require laravel/breeze --dev` というパスでコマンド入力しました。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/hq7wa8eml96g1w) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実際に試した訳ではないので憶測を含みますが、関連するファイルを Windows 側に置いて `/mnt` 経由で参照するのではなく、WSL の Linux 内にコピー等で直接配置した状態で試してみてください。

Windows と Linux で利用されるファイルシステムはそれぞれ異なるので、Linux から見て Windows 上のファイルに対してファイル権限に関する操作を行おうとした際にエラーが起きているように見えます。

Comment: ディレクトリを直接Linux配下にすることで権限問題が解消されました！ご回答いただき有難うございました。